# ZFW 3 странное поведение обьявленой переменной

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework-3

В конструкторе объявляю переменную $sqln, и обращаясь к ней внутри функции например как $this->sqln=new MySQL(), получаю ошибку:

```
File:
    /var/www/webuseorg4/vendor/zendframework/zend-view/src/Helper/Escaper/AbstractHelper.php:72
Message:
    Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion
```

Контроллер:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Common\CommonServices;
use Application\Common\MySQL;
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController{        
    var $sqln; 
    public function __construct(array $config) {     
            $this->sqln=new MySQL();
            $this->sqln->connect($config['database']['host'],$config['database']['username'],$config['database']['password'],$config['database']['basename']);            
...

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить ключевое слово $var на $private:

```
<?php
namespace Application\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Application\Common\CommonServices;
use Application\Common\MySQL;
class IndexController extends AbstractActionController{        
    private $sqln; <-- edit
    public function __construct(array $config) {     
            $this->sqln=new MySQL();
            $this->sqln->connect($config['database']['host'],$config['database']['username'],$config['database']['password'],$config['database']['basename']);            
...

 }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. возможно, стоит привести пример использования. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]